# "Bad Data" CryptographicException

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

First, I have only written the code below for academic purposes. The reason I say this is because I am not putting this in a production environment, and therefor am "bypassing" some of the overhead that I would need to do if I was, I simply need to be able to encrypt/decrypt a string using the code below. I was able to do it a few time, but for some reason, I started receiving "CryptographicException Bad Data" and am not sure what might be causing the problem.

```
   private string RSAEncrypt(string value)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);

        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = _rsaContainerName;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048,cspParams))
        {
            encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(encryptedData, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

        }

    }



    private string RSADecrypt(string value)
    {

        byte[] encryptedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);

        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = _rsaContainerName;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048,cspParams))
        { 
            encryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(encryptedData,false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

        }
    }
```

It is only throwing this exception on the RSADecrypt call.

Any ideas? I read somewhere it might have to do with the expected size of encryptedData that is passed into RSA.Decrypt.

Thanks
        }

Comment: Uh, how are you passing the keys between the methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Convert the plaintext back and forth using a string-encoding (i.e. `Encoding.Unicode`).
- Convert the encrypted data back and forth using Base-64 (i.e. `Convert.[To/From]Base64String`);

Like this:

```
private string RSAEncrypt(string value)
{
    byte[] plaintext = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);

    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = _rsaContainerName;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048,cspParams))
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
}

private string RSADecrypt(string value)
{
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = _rsaContainerName;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048,cspParams))
    { 
        byte[] decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(encryptedData,false);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/11/10/491431.aspx

> Don't Roundtrip Ciphertext Via a String Encoding
>
> One common mistake that people make when using managed encryption
>   classes is that they attempt to store the result of an encryption
>   operation in a string by using one of the Encoding classes.  That
>   seems to make sense right?  After all, Encoding.ToString() takes a
>   byte[] and converts it to a string which is exactly what they were
>   looking for.
>
> ...
>
> Instead if you want to convert the ciphertext into a string, use
>   Base64 encoding.
>
> ...
>
> Results in code that works every time, since base 64 encoding is
>   guaranteed to be able to accurately represent any input byte sequence.

There is a good, correct example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx

Comment: I have seen that article, but I dont quite get what the fix is or what in my code I would need to change...could you help point this out?

Comment: But OP uses `ByteConverter.GetString` not `Encoding.ToString`

Comment: I am still a bit confused, I have made edits above, is this what you are saying to do?

Comment: You must not use Encoding here. You need to write the string that's passed into RSAEncrypt to a stream, probably using a StreamWriter. You can then call RSA.Encrypt(YourStream.ToArray()). The string that's passed into RSADecrypt needs to be converted from Base64 *before* it is decrypted.

Comment: I see what you are saying to do, I am just having a bit of trouble mapping it all out, I have tried to find references, but not sure how to go from a string to the byte[] that I need to pass into my encryption methods, can you please provide a small snippet of wha tI would need to do to go from a string to the byte[] which is what is passed into my RSA.Encrypt() and RSA.Decrypt()

Comment: YourStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(YourStream); YourStreamWriter.Write(YourString);

Answer (score 1):

**RSA** is not meant to encrypt large objects. You'll get exceptions is you go over the padding limit. The actual limit is based on the padding itself (using `false` means you're using the **old** PKCS#1 v1.5 padding) and the length of your public key (2048 bits).

The right way to use `RSA` with large object is to encrypt the large object with a symmetric key (e.g. a 256 bits `AES` secret key) and the encrypt this **small** key with your `RSA` public key.

You can find code to do such things on my [blog](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem this was because I put this in my Global.asax file to convert Url into lowercase.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //   Don't rewrite requests for content (.png, .css) or scripts (.js)
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Content/") ||
            Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Scripts/"))
            return;

        If uppercase chars exist, redirect to a lowercase version
        var url = Request.Url.ToString();
       if (Regex.IsMatch(url, @"[A-Z]"))
        {
            Response.Clear();
           Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
           Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            Response.AddHeader("Location", url.ToLower());
            Response.End();
       }
    }
```

So

**Example**

If encryption is done with base64 string encode as

> http://localhost:11430/orderpreview?orderID=t4RZrnefb2a%253d&price=27.9

Then on hitting the action the "Application_BeginRequest" converting it into

> http://localhost:11430/orderpreview?orderID=t4rzrnefb2a%253d&price=27.9

You can see the RZ was captial converted into small rz this will fail the decryption.

**Solution**

Inside RouteConfig class RegisterRoutes method put this if you want the url in lowercase

```
        routes.Canonicalize().Www();
        routes.Canonicalize().Lowercase();
        routes.Canonicalize().NoTrailingSlash();
```