# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography

I am using following code to encrypt and decrypt a file:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Public Shared Sub ZeroMemory(ByVal addr As IntPtr, ByVal size As Integer)
End Sub
Public Function GenerateKey() As String
    ' Create an instance of a symmetric algorithm. The key and the IV are generated automatically.
    Dim desCrypto As DESCryptoServiceProvider = DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create()

    ' Use the automatically generated key for encryption. 
    Return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key)

End Function
Sub EncryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, _
              ByVal sOutputFilename As String, _
              ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    'Set secret key for DES algorithm.
    'A 64-bit key and an IV are required for this provider.
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    'Set the initialization vector.
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    'Create the DES encryptor from this instance.
    Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()
    'Create the crypto stream that transforms the file stream by using DES encryption.
    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                        desencrypt, _
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    'Read the file text to the byte array.
    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    'Write out the DES encrypted file.
    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    cryptostream.Close()
End Sub
Sub DecryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, _
   ByVal sOutputFilename As String, _
   ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    'A 64-bit key and an IV are required for this provider.
    'Set the secret key for the DES algorithm.
    DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
    'Set the initialization vector.
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    'Create the file stream to read the encrypted file back.
    Dim fsread As New FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    'Create the DES decryptor from the DES instance.
    Dim desdecrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor()
    'Create the crypto stream set to read and to do a DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
    Dim cryptostreamDecr As New CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    'Print out the contents of the decrypted file.
    Dim fsDecrypted As New StreamWriter(sOutputFilename)
    fsDecrypted.Write(New StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd)
    fsDecrypted.Flush()
    fsDecrypted.Close()
End Sub
```

Functions are called as:

```
Sub main()
    Dim sSecretKey As String
    Dim c As New Crpt.Crpt
    Dim fTest As FileStream = File.Create("d:\GKey.txt")
    sSecretKey = c.GenerateKey()
    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(sSecretKey)
    fTest.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fTest.Close()
    'Console.WriteLine(sSecretKey)
    'Console.Read()
    Dim gch As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(sSecretKey, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    c.EncryptFile("d:\test.txt", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\NRS.lic", sSecretKey)
    ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), sSecretKey.Length * 2)
    gch.Free()
End Sub
```

The above in this sub main I encrypted test.txt file to NRS.lic

While I am trying to decrypt it using:

```
Public Sub dcrpt()
    Dim C As New Crpt.Crpt
    Dim sKey As String
    sKey = "???:8w?"
    Dim gch As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(sKey, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    'C.DecryptFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "NRS.lic", "c:\Nrs.txt", "??5\????")
    C.DecryptFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\NRS.lic", "d:\Nrs.txt", sKey)
    ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), sKey.Length * 2)
    gch.Free()
End Sub
```

I am getting an exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146893819   Message=Bad Data.

Complete stack trace is:

> StackTrace:
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptData(SafeKeyHandle hKey,
>   Byte[] data, Int32 ib, Int32 cb, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32
>   outputOffset, PaddingMode PaddingMode, Boolean fDone)
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoAPITransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
>   inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
>          at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
>          at Crpt.Crpt.DecryptFile(String sInputFilename, String sOutputFilename, String sKey) in
>   d:\NRS\NikRosterScheduler\Crpt\Crpt.vb:line 70
>          at NikRosterScheduler.frmMDI.dcrpt() in d:\NRS\NikRosterScheduler\NikRosterScheduler\frmMDI.vb:line 17
>          at NikRosterScheduler.frmMDI.frmMDI_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\NRS\NikRosterScheduler\NikRosterScheduler\frmMDI.vb:line 60
>          at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)
>          at NikRosterScheduler.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

**NOTE:**

when I try to decrypt the file just afte I encrypted it above using there is no error and it is working fine:

```
c.EncryptFile("d:\test.txt", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\NRS.lic", sSecretKey)
    c.DecryptFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\NRS.lic", "d:\nrs.txt", sSecretKey)
```

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9659928/2319909

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I am not able to understand how and where can I store the key generated for future use if it cannot be used as string? Do I need to change sSecretKey at the time of encryption?

Comment: I think the key bit you are missing is the Base64 encoding, so the binary can be stored as text.