# Encrypt and decrypt a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to crypt and later decrypt a MemoryStream (original large PDF file). I tried the following code:

```
    public static string GenerateKey()
    {
        var desCrypto = (DESCryptoServiceProvider)DES.Create();

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
    }

    public static MemoryStream Encrypt(Stream fsInput,string sKey)
    {
        var fsEncrypted=new MemoryStream();

        var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey),
            IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
        };
        var desencrypt = des.CreateEncryptor();
        var cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,desencrypt,CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        var bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        fsInput.Close();

        fsEncrypted.Flush();
        fsEncrypted.Position = 0;
        return fsEncrypted;
    }

    public static MemoryStream Decrypt(Stream fsread,string sKey)
    {
        var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey),
            IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
        };

        var sOutputFilename = new MemoryStream();
        var desdecrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
        var cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,desdecrypt,CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        var fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
        fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
        fsDecrypted.Flush();
        fsDecrypted.Close();
        sOutputFilename.Position = 0;

        return sOutputFilename;
    }
```

Call example:

```
    var sSecretKey = FileHelper.GenerateKey();
    var encyptedPdfContent = FileHelper.Encrypt(httpPostedFile.InputStream, sSecretKey);

    var decryptedPdfContent = FileHelper.Decrypt(encyptedPdfContent, sSecretKey);
```

Encrypt seems to work as expected but when I try to decrypt

```
fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
```

returns me `Bad Data` Exception.

What's wrong in my code?

I saw other posts and all of them are related to the string encoding (Encoding.Unicode). I don't have a string. I have a memorystream that is not encoded at all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Bad Data" CryptographicException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659898/bad-data-cryptographicexception)

Comment: I saw this post and it is related to the string encoding (Encoding.Unicode). I don't have a string. I have a memorystream that is not encoded at all!

Comment: I know but I just assumed you'd read all the contents in then pass a string in instead of the stream

Comment: the memorystream is just a PDF file read from disk.

Comment: So read the pdf file using `File.ReadAllText` or something similar if you can, also I saw posts regarding the `CryptoStream` not flushing at the end if it is only a partial block so you may have to do that. Maybe after the call to `cryptoStream.Write` call `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock` I think it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add following code in decrypt method

```
des.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to flush the `cryptoStream` after the call to `Write` this can be done using `FluchFinalBlock`:

```
cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
cryptostream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

Also in your `Decrypt` method you are disposing of the return stream by closing the `StreamWriter` so just remove this line:

```
fsDecrypted.Close();
```

Comment: The error was fixed adding `PaddingMode.Zeros` but your answer was usefull too! Thanks

Comment: @danyolgiax No problem I made the changes above to your code and it also worked, might be worth using them both just to make sure